# Java heap space on second time I create a thread

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, microservices, heap-memory

I have an @Async method to read and process an Excel file. This method (service method) is called from a microservice endpoint (controller). My method looks like this:

```
  @Transactional
  @Async
  public void load(InputStream file, boolean save, boolean deleteYear) throws IOException {
    try {
      OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
      file.close();

      XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);

      SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

      XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

      InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId1");

      InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);

      parser.parse(sheetSource);

      sheet2.close();

      SheetHandlerService sheetHandlerService = (SheetHandlerService) parser.getContentHandler();
      LOG.info("end processing data");
      
      if (deleteYear) { 
        deleteTable();
      }
      
      if (save) {
        saveCorrect();
        saveErrors();
      }
      
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    
  }
```

When I call the microservice from postman, it launch this function but it works just the first time. When I call the microservice for a second time I got this error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Shoul I clean the heap space at the end of the method or something similar? And how can I do that?

Comment: Java is garbage-collected. It's not expected that you do any steps to manually manage the memory. You might have a memory leak. The way you handle resources is not very good. If your code throws an exception then things will be left open. Consider a 'finally' block instead. You may also just not be giving the JVM enough heap space.

Comment: Good suggest @Michael .. I will add the finally clause but the first time the method works correctly and the second time I got the heap space error so it's not because of objects I think or what I do on my code, it must be something about the thread creation. And I cant change the heap space because it's a company server where I am running the code.

Comment: Your company will certainly have provision for having different JVMs with different heap space. It may be that your service just requires more than the default. I'm not saying that *is* the case, but it's a possibility. You should at least consider the case that the out-of-memory error is not actually a bug in your code. In any case, you should search for how to take a heap dump and how to analyze it.